# How Airflow determines when to re-import a DAG file?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

I'm seeing some interesting behavior how Airflow treats an existing DAG file. For example, I have a DAG file like this:

```
# my_pipeline.py

from dag_gen import DagGenerator

g = globals()
g.update(DagGenerator.generate())
```

In the code above, `DagGenerator.generate()` returns a dictionary with two items:

```
{
    'my_dag': DAG(...),
    'my_op': DummyOperator(...),
}
```

Technically, this code should be equivalent to:

```
# my_pipeline_equivalent.py

my_dag = DAG(...)
my_op = DummyOperator(...)
```

For some reason, the file `my_pipeline.py` is not being picked up by Airflow while `my_pipeline_equivalent.py` can be picked up without any problem.

However, if I add the following code in `my_pipeline.py`, both dags (i.e. `my_dag` and `my_dag2`) can be picked up.

```
# my_pipeline.py

from dag_gen import DagGenerator

g = globals()
g.update(DagGenerator.generate())

# newly added
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator

x = DAG(
    'my_dag2',
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
    default_args={
        "retries": 2, # If a task fails, it will retry 2 times.
    },
    tags=['example'],
)
b = DummyOperator(task_id='d3', dag=x)
```

What makes this stranger is if now I comment out the newly added part like below, `my_dag` can still be picked up while `my_dag2` is gone.

```
# my_pipeline.py

from dag_gen import DagGenerator

g = globals()
g.update(DagGenerator.generate())

# newly added
#from airflow import DAG
#from datetime import datetime
#from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator

#x = DAG(
#    'my_dag2',
#    schedule_interval="@daily",
#    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
#    catchup=False,
#    default_args={
#        "retries": 2, # If a task fails, it will retry 2 times.
#    },
#    tags=['example'],
#)
#b = DummyOperator(task_id='d3', dag=x)
```

However, if I actually delete the commented code, `my_dag` is gone as well. In order to add `my_dag` back, I have to add back `my_dag2` code without the comment (the commented `my_dag2` code, which worked previously, doesn't work now).

Could anyone help me understand what's going here? If I remember correctly, Airflow has some logic to determine when/if to import/re-import a Python file. Does anyone know where that logic lives in code?

Thanks.

Some additional find-outs. Once I have both DAGs (`my_dag` and `my_dag2`) being picked up. If I change `my_pipeline.py` to only keep the DAG import, `my_dag` can still be picked up, even if I commented out the import, but I cannot remove that line. If I do remove it, `my_dag` would be gone again.

```
# my_pipeline.py

from dag_gen import DagGenerator

g = globals()
g.update(DagGenerator.generate())

# from airflow import DAG
```

My guess is Airflow must be reading the python file and looking for that import as string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you follow the steps that Airflow takes to process the files, you will get to this [line of code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/ae7bf474109410fa838ab2728ae6d581cdd41808/airflow/utils/file.py#L356):

```py
return all(s in content for s in (b'dag', b'airflow'))
```

Which means that the Airflow file processor will ignore files that don't contain the two words `dag` and `airflow`.

If you want to process your module, and where you already have the word `dag`, you can just add a comment in the beginning contains the word `airflow`:

```py
# airflow
from dag_gen import DagGenerator

g = globals()
g.update(DagGenerator.generate())
```

Or just renaming the class `DagGenerator` to `AirflowDagGenerator` to solve the problem in all the modules.